# PHP: Why my PHPExcel_cell set an empty column as HighestColumn?

Tags: php, excel, yii2, phpexcel

I'm trying to read data from an Excel file that has been uploaded using `use PHPExcel_Cell;`. In my Excel, the data actually write in Column **A** up to **Y** (25 Column), but my system get the highest column is **AMK**. So the system give an error because of each column from **Z** up to **AMK** doesn't contain a data.

This is the code that I use to read the highest column:

```
$colNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
echo $colNumber;
```

and below is the result

> AMK

You can see here, that the Excel file only contain data upto column **Y**
[image]

#### Why my PHPEXCEL_cell doesn't avoid the empty column and set the last column that contain data as the highest column?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Depends where your value for `$highestColumn` comes from. There are two functions built into PHPExcel for reporting the highest column, and you make no mention of which (if either) you have used.

The first of these is `getHighestColumn()`, which uses the stored highest column value from the file which has been read. Note that this applies because the column is referenced somewhere in the loaded file, not necessarily because it is a cell containing data, but that may be referenced in page settings, or with a style, etc. It is also a static value: once read, it won't change, even if you add extra cells to the worksheet.

The second method is `getHighestDataColumn()`, which actually looks through every cell in the workheet, and returns the highest column where a cell exists. Because this method executes the check whenever it is called, it is costly in terms of performance, but it is accurate, and it will change as you add new cells to the worksheet.

Note (and this applies to both the `getHighestColumn()` and `getHighestDataColumn()` methods) that an empty string `''` or a null value are perfectly valid values for a cell; so a cell can exist even if it doesn't contain any displayable value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :D a few minute ago I'm reading your suggestion in this [issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/696). I just trying your suggestion and you're right. It's work, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Facing a similiar problem. In my case there are a bunch of empty columns in the array for the reason Mark mentioned. However here's a workaround, that you can get the highest non-empty column with:

```
 public function getHighestNonEmptyColumn($worksheet)
    {
        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestDataRow();
        $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestDataColumn();

        $alphabet = range($highestColumn, 'A');
        $sequence = range('1', $highestRow);
        $highestNonEmptyColumns = array();

        foreach ($alphabet as $letter) {
            foreach ($sequence as $row) {
                if ($worksheet->getCell($letter . $row)->getValue() != null) {
                    $highestNonEmptyColumns[] = $letter;
                }
            }
        }

        return max($highestNonEmptyColumns);
    }
```

For me getHighestDataColumn() returned Z. Using this you can get the highest column which is non-empty.

Quite sure it's not cost effective but at least it works.